# stopping an excel VBA macro from closing

Tags: vba, excel

I've written some very basic VBA code to do a simple task: remind me to fill in my timesheet (which is an Excel s/sheet). it's worked for me for many years while I went to the office, turned on the computer and had Excel in my 'startup' folder. However, now my life has changed a bit and I use my laptop and don't tend to shut it down and therefore the macro doesn't get fired up.

Here's how it opens:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:00:00"), "box"
    If TimeValue("17:00:00") < Time Then
       Run ("box")
    End If
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
    Run ("morning")
End Sub
```

here's 'box':

```
Sub box()

    response = MsgBox("Have you filled in your timesheet?", vbYesNo, "timesheet")

    If response = vbYes Then
        ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
    End If
    If response = vbNo Then
        Workbooks("timesheet2015 - GZ.xlsm").Activate
        ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    End If
End Sub
```

And here's 'morning'

```
Sub morning()
    response = MsgBox("Did you fill in your timesheet yesterday?", vbYesNo, "timesheet")

    If response = vbYes Then End
    If response = vbNo Then
        Workbooks("timesheet2015 - GZ.xlsm").Activate
        ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    End If
End Sub
```

I've been scratching my head working out if there's a way to stop the macro from ending once it's run once. I don't want to have some huge endless loop or it will slow the laptop down. I'm sure there's a simple way to do it so would love your help.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put the timesheet Workbook in your Excel's `XLStart` folder. This will open the workbook every time you open Excel. The use the workbook's `_Open` and `_Close` event handlers to prompt you to fill out the timesheet?

Or, put these procedures in another workbook or Add-in which loads with Excel (probably also in the XLStart or AddIns folder) that way you don't have to keep *this* file open perpetually. You can still use `OnTime` with the latter method.

Comment: Thanks David, I do already do that - the issue is this: I leave my laptop on (only close down every few days). So, when I start-up from scratch, it opens Excel and opens the VBA all fine - it's just that by the next day, it has closed down the macro and it doesn't automatically open the macro. is there a way so that every day at 5pm it can run the ontime command without me having to open up excel?

Comment: perhaps if you could expand on the 'addins' folder which loads with excel - that would be a good start - as I'm not sure what that does or how to access it. thank you!

Comment: Explaining what an add-in is, where it resides, and how it works is too broad. There are literally thousands of resources where this has been explained already. Google is your friend.  Otherwise, you have to have the file open to run a procedure at a given time with the `Application.OnTime` method. If you don't have the file open I think you can use Windows Task Scheduler. I've never done this, so google it if you don't know how it works (because I don't know how it works).

Comment: ok, thanks David, I will experiment and see where I get to! best, Gus